# Why my bomb impact radius and explosion effect instantiate in diffrent possition than it should?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im working on bomb system in Unity 3D. I have uploaded some explosion effects from Unity Asset Store and I want implement them into my project. I want to plant bomb with key "K" then wait 3sec to detonate it with explosion effect and give some damage to nearby objects. The problem is that explosion appears in such different position as it should. In my opinion this is Editor problem , the code looks fine. I will give you some screenshoots(https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Yzymch9RdTa-E6RkbvvyfzMWjMJHo52/view?usp=sharing)and my bomb script :

```
public class BoombScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject boombEffect;

[SerializeField]
private float radius;
[SerializeField]
private float force;
[SerializeField]
private int explosiveDamage;

public void Explode()
{
    Instantiate(boombEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

    Debug.Log("Transform" + transform);
    Debug.Log("Position" + transform.position);

    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);

    foreach(Collider rangedObject in colliders)
    {
        GateScript Gate = rangedObject.GetComponent<GateScript>();
        Rigidbody rb = rangedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        if(Gate != null)
        {
            Gate.GateDestroy(explosiveDamage);
        }

        if(rb != null)
        {
            rb.AddExplosionForce(force, transform.position, radius);
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerator WaitForExplode()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    Explode();
    
}
```

}

Comment: You know that `file:///C:/Users/szzie/Downloads/242761800_884079415543069_2145670916336461210_n.jpg` .. is not a link we can open right? ^^

Comment: @derHugo lmao. Now we got a protected google drive file instead

Comment: @zielu We can't access your picture, it's protected. You probably need to change its sharing settings.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Yzymch9RdTa-E6RkbvvyfzMWjMJHo52/view?usp=sharing

Comment: now it should works :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my opinion this is Editor problem , the code looks fine.

In general I would always doubt such a statement.

I can only guess but if I understand you correctly you rather want to use the position of your object the moment when you start the Coroutine, not the one after 3 seconds:

```
// instead of using the current "reansform.position" rather
// use the pre-stored position passed in via parameter
public void Explode(Vector3 position)
{
    Instantiate(boombEffect, position, Quaternion.identity);

    Debug.Log("Transform" + transform);
    Debug.Log("Position" + position);

    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(position, radius);

    foreach(Collider rangedObject in colliders)
    {
        GateScript Gate = rangedObject.GetComponent<GateScript>();
        Rigidbody rb = rangedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        if(Gate != null)
        {
            Gate.GateDestroy(explosiveDamage);
        }

        if(rb != null)
        {
            rb.AddExplosionForce(force, position, radius);
        }
    }
}

// If really needed you could still also have an overload 
// e.g. if at some places you actually call this method from the outside 
// immediately
public void Explode()
{
    Explode(transform.position);
}

public IEnumerator WaitForExplode()
{
    // Store the position when the routine is started
    var position = transform.position;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    // Instead of using the current position rather pass in
    // the previously stored one of when the routine was started
    Explode(position);
}
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Yzymch9RdTa-E6RkbvvyfzMWjMJHo52/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried your code and still it's the same problem :/

Comment: You think that the problem is with the coroutine ?

Comment: @zielu do you maybe have some strange offset between the pivot point of your objects (`transform.position`) and where the visual elements are placed?

Comment: No, I haven't got any offset , Im attaching my BombManager script which is responsible for bomb planting at bomb check , the bomb check is placed behind player's body. Maybe there is an issue. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ssgCO4j9DY9010dZ3fqcuM0jeDLF-XuJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @zielu I don't quite see how your `BombManager` is related to the `BombScript` and how that is related to the player object ... but to me it seems like in general you are using a position/offset you do not want to use ^^